# How to monitor NFS load from userland?

Tags: linux, nfs, performance-monitoring, rhel5, io

Apologies if I'm not using the proper jargon (although I'm a longtime linux user, I'm not an admin) or if this is a FAQ (though searching SE got lots of hits, I didn't see anything quite like this question):

I'm a user on a science cluster (with jobs managed by PBS/Torque, on RHEL5, FWIW). I'm about to start my first really-big job, so I asked the admin some configuration questions, to avoid stupid mistakes. I was mostly right, but he added the advice to "make sure you are not hammering the disk server with too much I/O," with followup to "use top [to] see if the nfs is going nuts."

How to do that? This is a cluster, so a lot is going on "behind the scenes" that is transparent to me. Plus I have next-to-no privileges. I also am limited to CLI via SSH, but that's the least of my problems. On the plus side, I do seem to be able to shell into any of the compute nodes, including those with attached disk(s).

So I'm wondering, how best to monitor NFS from userland? I know a little bit about `top` and NFS, so I know I can do

```
top -p$(pgrep nfsd -d ',')
```

to get the list of NFS processes (no?). But what I'd really like to know--again, as a user (I have neither `sudo` nor root) on RHEL5 (yes, we're still running that)--are

1. One, or a few, aggregate statistics for NFS load across all NFS processes. Is this something I can get from `top` or another tool, without scraping output and doing my own math? And should I be monitoring processes other than `nfsd`?
2. Advice concerning quantification of "NFS going nuts." If I can get one/few aggregate statistics, I can presumably get a pre-my-job baseline, but that still doesn't tell me "how high is too high."

**Note:** `top` appears not to be the tool to use for this task, but at least it is available to me. The list of tools which are *not* available include

1. [nfsstat](https://serverfault.com/a/558171/95940)
2. iostat
3. iotop

Answer (score 7):

Looking at top output is completely wrong. It's about the IOPS. To get a view on the NFS statistics, use `nfsstat`:

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badauth    badclnt    xdrcall
40833255   0          0          0          0       

Server nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink     
0         0% 1411374   3% 107       0% 43169     0% 747514    1% 790       0% 
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod        
38138706 93% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus  
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 491559    1% 
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit       
6         0% 12        0% 6         0% 0         0%
```

---

If you have a monitoring program (fer instance, Zabbix) you can add a UserParameter to watch them:

```
# NFS stats
UserParameter=nfs.v3.server[*],nfsstat -s -l | awk 'BEGIN {FS=": *"}/v3 server.*$1:/ {print $$2}'
```

and make pretty graphs:
[image]

How high is too high? It totally depends on your workload:

[image: nfs graph]

You need to watch the filesystem and disk *latency* to see if you're overloading the disks.

Comment: Looks great! but unfortunately `which nfsstat` gets no response. Is this something I can install as a user (e.g., to `~/bin/nfsstat`)? I tend to doubt it, but thought I'd ask ...

Comment: The proper thing to do is to go to the admin of the server and tell them that the necessary tools for doing your job aren't available.

Comment: I'll try, but note that it's precisely the cluster admin who's telling me to use `top`.

Comment: Perhaps *he* doesn't know and is expecting you to discover the right way to monitor the situation?